# Posting XML in comment section

Tags: comments, xml

Users post XML data in my comments section frequently due to the nature of my content, but due to the way the comments work, the elements are consumed and do not appear properly. In fact, when I look at the comments through dashboard, the tags are completely gone.

For example, if you wrote

```
<person>
   some name
</person>
```

All I would see is

```
some name
```

If I use `pre` tags, that works fine, so presumably the comments are being consumed as HTML, and I've also enabled markdown to make it a bit easier, but I figured it's easier for my visitors to just remove this HTML comment formatting.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting your users to be able to add the xml tags into the comment form, without having them removed, it would be best to add a filter to `pre_process_comment` so as to add `<pre>` tags around the comment before it's posted to the DB.